# Selecting a Range on the X-Axis in Recharts

Tags: reactjs, crossfilter, recharts

I'm trying to reproduce the [Airline on-time performance](http://crossfilter.github.io/crossfilter/) crossfilter demo in React. We're using [Recharts](http://recharts.org/en-US/). One feature is the ability to drag a selection window across a bar chart. Is this possible in Recharts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like there's [an example on the Recharts page](http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/HighlightAndZoomLineChart) for line charts. It involves the chart's mouseMove, mouseDown, and mouseUp event handlers.

Answer (score -1):

I think the op is looking for a slider solution something like this on [bizcharts](https://bizcharts.net/product/BizCharts4/demo/374)  its a very common thing to have on charts and think it will be valuable to have something simular on recharts